# Using PIE to style Bootstrap element (btn)

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, styling, css3pie

I have created a list of styles to override the main bootstrap.css file, for IE versions 9 and below. Just about all elements I've overridden with the PIE syntax required to round the corners of an element (using `border-radius:`) are displaying normally. Except for the buttons (styled with `class="btn"`)

For some reason, these buttons are not displaying at **all** (let alone having the proper rounding of the corners I'm looking for. I've tried just about all I can think of. If I remove the style for .btn, the button shows up again, normally (without the rounded corners) but if I put it back in, the button disappears.

Here is the CSS:

```
.btn {
    border-radius: 4px;
    behavior: url(js/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

Where could the css be going wrong? Other elements with the precise, same style are visible on the screen fine, and rounding the corners, as well.

UPDATE:
I've discovered this only occurs on my submit button, within the element with the class `.form-actions` and the button **does** display and correctly renders the round corners outside of that element. I've narrowed the problem, but I still need it to display within the `<div class="form-actions">` element.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question, but in case anyone else finds it, adding position:relative worked for me in IE8. Haven't tested it in 9.

```
.btn {
    border-radius: 4px;
    behavior: url(js/pie/PIE.htc);
    position: relative;
}
```